# How can i update the mercurial branch with other branch

Tags: mercurial, merge

I have two branches `branch A` and `branch B`. I want to update the branch B with all the contents from `branch A` , without modifying anything in `branch A`.

I still want to be on `branch B` to commit the changes. How can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hg checkout B
hg merge A
hg commit
```

That will merge A's changes into B and create a new commit on B with A entirely unchanged.

Comment: what if i do `hg update -C -r <revision number of branch A head>`

Comment: That does the same thing only it's more typing and harder to do: `checkout` is an alias for `update`, using the branch name is the same as looking up the revision number of the head of that branch, and `-r` is optional for update/checkout.